# Trouble with stack navigator and tab navigator for react native

Tags: javascript, react-native, expo

I'm trying to navigate from a tab navigator to a screen on my stack navigator but I am getting this error:

[image]

Is there a specific way to navigate back to the stack navigator after being in the tab navigator?

Here is where I am using onPress:

```
onPress={() => this.onProfileButtonPressed()}
```

The function to onProfileButtonPressed looks like:

```
constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        filteredCellArray: [],
        masterCellArray: []
    };
    this.onProfileButtonPressed = this.onProfileButtonPressed.bind(this);
}

onProfileButtonPressed = () => {
    this.props.navigation.navigate('Profile', this);
    console.log("Profile Button Pressed");
};
```

Below is the router with the stack and tab navigator:

```
const TabNav = TabNavigator({
  Profile:{
    screen: Profile,
    tabBarOptions: {
      showLabel: false
    }
  },
  Books:{
    screen: BookTab
  },
  Tutors:{
    screen: TutorTab
  },
  Furniture:{
    screen: FurnitureTab
  },
  Roommate:{
    screen: RoommateTab
  },
  Carpool:{
    screen: CarpoolTab
  }},
  {
    tabBarComponent: TabBarBottom,
    tabBarPosition: 'bottom',
    swipeEnabled: false,
    animationEnabled: false,
    lazy: true,
    initialRouteName: 'Books'
});

export const FeedStack = StackNavigator({
  SignIn: {
    screen: SignIn,
    navigationOptions: {
      title: "Login"
    }
  },
  SignUp: {
    screen: SignUp,
    navigationOptions: {
      title: "Create An Account"
    }
  },
  ForgotPassword: {
    screen: ForgotPassword,
    navigationOptions: {
      title: "Forgot Password"
    }
  },
  Profile: {
    screen: Profile,
    navigationOptions: {
      title: "Your Profile"
    }
  },
  TabNav: {
    screen: TabNav,
    navigationOptions: {
      title: "Home"
    }
  },
  listing: {
    screen: listing,
    navigationOptions: {
      title: "Listing"
    }
  }
})
```

Comment: Please provide [mcve]

Comment: Please show us your navigator stacks' setup. If `StackNavigator` isn't under `TabNavigator`, then it won't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your problem is that currently your `TabNavigator` is inside `StackNavigator`. It's supposed to be other way around.

In addition, since you don't want to display it in all the views (like in signup, I guess), you need to customise it. Read further specs from the documentation on hiding the TabBar.

But the basic logic with tabs is that the stacks are inside them.

And if you bind a function to the scope inside `constructor`, then you should refer to it like:
`onPress={this.onProfileButtonPressed}`.

Comment: I currently have the app launch the stack first since our stack navigator has the login screen we want. How would we go about this if we were to put the TabNavigator is inside StackNavigator?

Comment: @frog4 The logic with initial routes and app behaviour is similar even when stack is inside the tab. Only thing you need to take care of with custom logic is that when tabs are visible. Unfortunately I can't provide any examples atm, but I hope you find one.

Comment: 'It's supposed to be other way around.' Not necessarily